# Azure AD B2C verification link with dynamic redirect uri & response type

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently implementing custom mail verification for B2C following the sample found on github https://github.com/yoelhor/aadb2c-verification-link 
When generating the link I would like to pick up the values for **redirect_uri** and **response_type** from the original request instead of defining it in appsettings. Is there a way to pass both query parameters on to the mail app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hit this as well, making something similar for password reset. As far as I can tell, those values are not available from claim resolvers, so you can't get them. Unless you use custom query parameters which duplicate the values.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you think of any reason why the attributes are not available as claim resolvers? Might there be any security concerns?

Comment: Nope, that's something I think I'll try asking from the product team